# How to fix a mistake in an accepted paper?

Tags: publications, paper-submission, errors-erratum, proofreading

I submitted a joint paper and it is accepted by a journal after two minor revisions. 
In the last revision, there is a misunderstanding between my coauthor and me, so the last revisions still contained several mistakes.
The manuscript has gone into production and the journal will send the proofs.

How do I fix the mistake?

(1) Should I contact the journal immediately and send revised manuscript?

Or

(2) should I wait the proof-reading version and ask the journal to fix my mistakes?

I prefer the first option, since this is faster and pointing out the mistake in the proof-reading version is more difficult than fixing the original manuscript. 
The manuscript is written in LATEX. 
However, I also understand that the first option will be a problem to the journal.

Comment: What kind of mistakes?

Comment: Missing minus sign, missing the ambient space, a mistake in the naming of variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Send them both a revised version and a detailed explanation what needs to be changed. Depending on where your submission is in the production process, they may prefer the former or the latter. Do it as quickly as possible.